# Resample by date and add new columns of sum based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to resample DataFrame on daily/weekly/monthly basis. I am confused and clue less how it should be. How do I resample with conditions and sum the newly created row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'date': ['2014-08-4 19:00:00', '2014-08-5 10:09:00', '2014-08-4 21:04:00','2014-08-5 22:07:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00', '2014-08-4 22:09:00', '2014-08-5 22:09:00'], 
    'id'  :[4,5,7,8,2,3,5,2,1,1,4,4,2,4,5,1,3,9,7,9],
    'qty' :[9,5,7,8,3,3,5,2,1,1,4,4,2,4,5,1,3,5,7,9], 
    'type' :[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0] 
})
inward = df['type'] == 0
outward = df['type'] == 1

df1 = df.join(df[inward].groupby(['id'])['qty'].sum(), on='id', rsuffix='_inward')
df2 = df.join(df[outward].groupby(['id'])['qty'].sum(), on='id', rsuffix='_outward')

df1['qty_outward'] = df2['qty_outward']
```

I'm trying to get data in following format

```
    date                 id qty_inward  qty_outward
0   2014-08-04 19:00:00  4  8           13
1   2014-08-05 10:09:00  5  5           0
2   2014-08-04 21:04:00  7  0           14
3   2014-08-05 22:07:00  8  8           0
4   2014-08-05 22:09:00  2  4           3
5   2014-08-05 22:09:00  3  0           3
8   2014-08-04 22:09:00  1  0           1
9   2014-08-05 22:09:00  1  0           2
14  2014-08-04 22:09:00  5  5           5
16  2014-08-04 22:09:00  3  3           0
17  2014-08-05 22:09:00  9  14          0
```

These I'm doing for creating opening and closing stock for weekly/daily/monthly basis. My approach may be wrong if you have suggestions please provide.

Comment: where is your approach?

Comment: Just updated, I was first trying to sum the values and then do resample. But this not giving any output.

Comment: Are you sure your output is correct? `df1 = df.groupby([df.date, df.id, df.type]).sum().unstack()` return for first row something different. Can you explain it why? Or typo?

Comment: Grouping it by date will not return proper result as, the time will be different. Also resample by daily is not applied in groupby. You can see when we do groupby by date there is multiple entry for same id and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) - it is new feature in [0.18.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations). Last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) second level to columns:

```
print (df.groupby(['id', 'type'])
         .resample('D')['qty']
         .sum()
         .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(level=0))

type        id  qt_inward  qt_outward
date                                 
2014-08-04   1          0           1
2014-08-05   1          0           2
2014-08-05   2          4           3
2014-08-04   3          3           0
2014-08-05   3          0           3
2014-08-04   4          8          13
2014-08-04   5          5           5
2014-08-05   5          5           0
2014-08-04   7          0          14
2014-08-05   8          8           0
2014-08-05   9         14           0
```

Comment: Hmmm, if use resample by day you lost time information. Is it problem?

Comment: Hey its what I was looking for, how we can have ID in separate column?